# Internet Explorer Compatibility Issues (CSSPlay Menu)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, menu

I've been running into the age-old problem of cross-browser compatibility ever since I began making websites, but this time I'm stumped.

I have a pure-CSS and HTML menu that I used from CSSPlay. It works flawlessly in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer. Can somebody help me figure out why? It works fine in IE9 Compatibility Mode, ironically.

Edit: Forgot the link. http://jsfiddle.net/Xh9Kz/

Also, I've been running into a lot of trouble with percentage differences between webkit and Internet Explorer browsers in general. While Webkit browsers also percentages to add up to 100%, IE seems to not do so. Does anyone have a resource for this so I can code to avoid it?

Thanks in advance. Merry Christmas everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code, it's just something common with the examples from CSSPlay, check the last question in the FAQ:

> 10.**The demonstration/menu does not work in IE8**
>       IE8 is very temperamental when it comes to multi-level demonstrations
>   and menus (not just mine). I will be
>   going through my demonstrations over
>   the coming months to get them to work
>   in IE8 but in the mean time the
>   easiest way is to switch IE8 into IE7
>   emulation mode which will cures all
>   problems.
>       To do this add the following meta tag immediately afer the  tag:
>       `<head>`
>       `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`

[here](http://jsbin.com/ugivi4)'s the same exact code but with the meta tag added :)

Comment: Is there a way to put it into IE-7 mode only for the menu? It wrecks some of the CSS3 elements on my page such as border-radius.

Comment: No, you cannot set the document mode on anything other than a document.